Error while running Next.js project: "TypeError: fetch failed" and "unable to verify the first certificate"
I encountered an error while trying to run my Next.js project using npm run dev. The error message is as follows:
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getVersionInfo (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader-webpack.js:215:21)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async HotReloaderWebpack.start (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader-webpack.js:607:28)
    at async startWatcher (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:156:5)
    at async setupDevBundler (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:775:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async initialize (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:78:30)    
    at async Server.<anonymous> (D:\Study\WebDev\My Projects\vtu\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:249:36) {
  cause: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {
    code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
  }
}


I run the command npm run dev in the project directory after setting up the NextJS project.
Observed the error message displayed in the console.
Expected Behavior:
The Next.js development server should start without any errors.
Additional Information:
I'm using Next.js version 14.2.2.
The error seems to be related to SSL certificate verification.
I've already tried setting strict-ssl to true in my npm configuration, but the issue persists.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

try this
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm start

It looks like the error you're encountering is related to TLS (Transport Layer Security) certificate verification.
And try again to check the following:
Environment Setup,
Network Configuration,
Update Dependencies,
Trust Certificate,
Check Certificate
or you can ignore the certificate validation:
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'
